# Coding a GUI in Java however my labels never seem to appear

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, bluej

I am creating a GUI using BlueJ - Java, i have made the entry boxes however i cant seem to add a label to go either above each one or to the left. Could anyone help me out and tell me where im going wrong ? My code is below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Log extends JFrame {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Log frameTabel = new Log();
    }

    JButton Confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Name", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField FullName = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField Address1line = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField postcode = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField Destination = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField Date = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField MilesTravelling = new JTextField(15);
    JLabel lblMsg = new JLabel ("Name",JLabel.LEFT);

    Log(){
        super("Customer GUI");
        setSize(300,400);
        setLocation(400,250);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        FullName.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
        Address1line.setBounds(70,80,150,20);
        postcode.setBounds(70,130,150,20);
        Destination.setBounds(70,180,150,20);
        Date.setBounds(70,230,150,20);
        MilesTravelling.setBounds(70,280,150,20);
        Confirm.setBounds(105,320,80,20);

        panel.add(lblMsg);
        panel.add(Confirm);
        panel.add(FullName);
        panel.add(Address1line);
        panel.add(postcode);
        panel.add(Destination);
        panel.add(Date);
        panel.add(MilesTravelling);
        getContentPane().add(label1);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use null layout. Yse code conventions. Variables in java should not start from capital letter. Move the setSize() just before the setVisible(true)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be adding your `panel` and `label` seperately to the content pane. I would probably call the `super.add()` instead.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: This is not your private help desk, but a public Q&A site.  Removing code from a Q&A is vandalism as the answers become nonsense.  Stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [JFrames ContentPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) uses [BorderLayou](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)t, BorderLayout has 5th areas and only one JComponent can be placed in the one of areas

.

```
getContentPane().add(label1); //JFrames CENTER area
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

- then last added JComponent can be visible

.

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

- suggestions don't to use `NullLayout` and `Log frameTabel = new Log();` should be wrapped into `invokeLater` (Swing GUI should be created and intialized on `EventDispatchThread`), more to see in Oracle tutorial `Initial Thread`